# twitter bootstrap 3.0 rc1 not using gutters between certain columns

Tags: html, css, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
.rounded-box(@border; @radius; @bg-color: transparent; @padding: 5px 10px) {
   border:1px solid @border;
   .border-top-radius(@radius);
   .border-bottom-radius(@radius);
   .border-left-radius(@radius);
   .border-right-radius(@radius);
   background-color: @bg-color;
   padding: @padding;
}
```

I have a mixin creating a rounded corner box, in the screenshot below, you can see that it does not have any spacing between each div, which has .make-column(4) applied to each.

*I do include the bootstrap.less into my main less file and run lessc to compile and this is in the screen shot you see is over 990px wide. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

```
@rounded-box-radius: 10px;
@rounded-box-border: #ccc;
@rounded-box-height:230px;
@box-bg-color: #eee;

.article {
    .make-column(4);
}

.promo {
    .make-column(4);
    .visible-lg;
    .rounded-box(@rounded-box-border, @rounded-box-radius);
    height: @rounded-box-height;
} // promo end
```

HTML

```
<div class="promo">
    Promo
</div>

<div class="article">
    <h3>Blog Entry 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor.</p>

    <div class="date">March 23, 2013</div>
    <div class="read-more"><a href="blog-detail.php" title="read more on this title">Read more</a></div>
</div>

<div class="promo">
    Promo
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think bootstrap 3 uses padding for column separation instead of margins. Your border wraps around the entire element, including the padding. You may need supply your own margin rules for column separation instead of padding to get bordered boxes with separation between them.

Answer (score 0):

[@jtlowe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314658/jtlowe) is right in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18127896/1596547 about the padding. But applying margin rules on your columns will break the grid (due to margins adds up with the width).

Use an extra container, just like here: [need spacing between divs using twitter bootstrap v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765629/need-spacing-between-divs-using-twitter-bootstrap-v3/18770955) (duplicate??)

**html**

```
<div class="promo">
    <div class="rounded-box">Promo</div>
</div>
```

**less**

```
.rounded-box(@border; @radius; @bg-color: transparent; @margin: 5px 10px) {
   border:1px solid @border;
   .border-top-radius(@radius);
   .border-bottom-radius(@radius);
   .border-left-radius(@radius);
   .border-right-radius(@radius);
   background-color: @bg-color;
   margin: @margin;
   height:@rounded-box-height;
}
```

NOTE apply the height (@rounded-box-height) here and replace the padding with margin