# Bootstrap 4 adding gutters to columns is it possible?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been scouring the web looking for an answer but I can't seem to find a answer regarding adding gutters to columns in BS4. Any articles I find that talk about adding gutters are referencing BS3. Even the BS4 Docs talk about removing them, but as far as I can tell there isn't any, right?

Is it even possible to add equal gutters that don't cause cols to break and wrap? If so how would you do it without messing with flex box?

I have a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/s8rm1f0q/5/) demonstrating the grid I'm trying to add gutters to. Any help I could get, or even if I could be pointed in the right direction I'd be grateful.

```css
.sec-accent {
  background-color: #fafcf5;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #9999cc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 blue" style="height:500px;">
        Hello World
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 blue" style="height:500px;">
        Hello World
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 blue" style="height:500px;">
        Hello World
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 blue" style="height:500px;">
        Hello World
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 blue" style="height:500px;">
        Hello World
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 blue" style="height:500px;">
        Hello World
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 blue" style="height:500px;">
        Hello World
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 blue" style="height:500px;">
        Hello World
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 blue" style="height:500px;">
        Hello World
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**EDIT: 9 April 2018**

I can see where I have mis-interpreted bootstrap gutters now and after some more digging I was able to come up with a solution to my problem.

> Added here in this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/s8rm1f0q/11/) for anyone looking for a solution like mine.

Thanks again for the assistance.

Regards, -B.

Comment: I assume you are talking about gutters as a margin not padding?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Bootstrap already has a "gutter" that creates spacing between cols... using padding. However, this gutter isn't apparent on the code you posted because the bg color is on the columns, instead of the column content: https://jsfiddle.net/1zab595j/ ... also, there's no difference in the gutter between v3 and v4 (it's still 30px padding) so all the old answers are relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765629/

Comment: I see now where I have mis-interpreted the concept. Thanks for the pointers. To clarify I'm looking for equal spacing around each column that doesn't offset the content in the columns or cause the cols to break early. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood about the gutters. Bootstrap 3 and 4 both already have 30px gutters between columns. The problem in your code is you have used the .blue class right in the divs with `col-*` class. You need to do this the other way. You should leave that div with only the `col-*` class. Try this code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="blue" style="height:500px;">
                Hello World
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="blue" style="height:500px;">
                Hello World
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="blue" style="height:500px;">
                Hello World
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="blue" style="height:500px;">
                Hello World
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="blue" style="height:500px;">
                Hello World
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="blue" style="height:500px;">
                Hello World
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="blue" style="height:500px;">
                Hello World
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="blue" style="height:500px;">
                Hello World
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="blue" style="height:500px;">
                Hello World
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying I see where I have mis-interpreted gutters now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a solution that works for me.

```
<div class="col col-4 col-lg-2 bg-primary border border-white"></div>
```

border border-white

Doesn't actually create a space but gives the effect of space between cols.  Only works if you have a bg-color obviously